# Django: how to retrieve a form search parameters in a django generic listView

Tags: django, html, django-views

how to retrieve a form search parameters in a django generic listView. My url is:

`url(r'postsearch$', views.PostsList.as_view(), name='postsearch'),`

My generic listview is:

```
class PostsList(generic.ListView):
model = Post
template_name = 'posts/post_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    localisation = #how to get location
    discipline = #how to get discipline

    return Post.objects.filter(.......)
```

and my form is:

```
<form class="form-inline text-center" action="{% url 'posts:postsearch' %}" id="form-searchLessons" method="get">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="typeCours" list="matieres" placeholder="Matieres: e.g. Math, Physique,.." name="discipline">
          <datalist id="matieres">
              <option value="value1">
              <option value="value2">
          </datalist>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Localisation" placeholder="Lieu: Bousaada, Douaouda,.." 
                name="localisation" onFocus="geolocate()">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-getLessons">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Trouver !
      </button>
    </form>
```

I want to get the Posts by applying a filter according to the lacalisation and matieres introduced in the search fields (in the form)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the search terms to your `url` regular expression.

```
url(r'postsearch/(?P<localisation>\w+)/(?P<descipline>\w+)/$', views.PostsList.as_view(), name='postsearch'),
```

(Note, mind the trailing slash)

In your `get_queryset` method you can use those given url parameters

```
def get_queryset(self):
    localisation = self.kwargs['localisation'] or None
    discipline = self.kwargs['discipline'] or None
    filters = {}

    if localisation:
         filters.update(localisation: localisation)
    if discipline:
         filters.update(discipline: discipline)

    return Post.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Eventually you should relocate getting the parameters outside your `get_queryset`, but that is up to you.

**I'm not sure about the security risks doing it this way. Anyone having more information about the security risks during this operation, please share.**

Comment: It does not recognize the keyword localisation and discipline, so I used json to get the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I build a library that can help you to solve this problem, you just have to put in the searchable_fields the attributes you want to filter and it will take care of the rest.

https://github.com/SchroterQuentin/django-search-listview